# Sybase Login Failed Count

Tags: authentication, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am new to Sybase and I need help with few things.

I need to find failed login attempts for an user before successful login.
Wherever I search I get only about Setting Maximum failed logins.

I need to know the number of attempts the user made before successful login.

And I would also like to know how to check the code of system procedures.
`sp_helptext` but I dont see any output in result area, I see just the execution time

Comment: Have you some code example?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Sunil to SO.

to find the login attempts a user made you can use the following sp_displaylogin stored procedure. it will give you a lot of information about a specific user. check out the "current failed login attempts" field below:

```
1> sp_displaylogin 'sa'
2> go
Suid: 1
Loginame: sa
Fullname: 
Default Database: master
Default Language: 
Auto Login Script: 
Configured Authorization:
    sa_role (default ON)
    sso_role (default ON)
    oper_role (default ON)
    sybase_ts_role (default ON)
Locked: NO
Date of Last Password Change: Jul 26 2005 10:42AM 
Password expiration interval: 0 
Password expired: NO 
Minimum password length: 6 
Maximum failed logins: 0 
Current failed login attempts: 
Authenticate with: NONE
```

To see all system procedures you most likely will first have to switch to the sybsystemprocs database and execute the `sp_helptext` procedure there:

```
1> use sybsystemprocs
2> go
1> sp_helptext sp_who
2> go
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, i dont see anything happening when I run "use sybsystemprocs" in interactice sql.
All I see is execution time when I run "sp_helptext sp_who"
Where will it be displayed??

And also, when I try and run sp_displaylogin it says no procedure found!

Comment: you may want to give us some more information about the Sybase Product you are using. Is it ASE? is it IQ or Anywhere? It seems to me you are not using the Standard isql utility which Sybase is providing.

Comment: I am using sybase anywhere 16

Comment: what about querying the SYSUSER system table? see more details here: http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/sysuser-system-view.html

Comment: Problem with SYSUSER table was that it made the failed attempts to 0 on successful login.
I added an even at login failure and was able top capture the failed attempts and display them on pop up on successful login,
however I am facing a different problem now!
Can you please take a look here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897338/cannot-open-interactive-sql-from-command-prompt