# Cannot open Interactive sql from command prompt

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I have added my own procedure to run as soon as user logs, using

SET OPTION PUBLIC.post_login_procedure = 'xxx.Myprocedure';

I need to set custom message on pop up this provides when user logs in. The pop up is working, when I manually login in from Sybase central.
however, when I run dbisql -c "DSN=myDSN" from command prompt Interactive sql opens and I get the popup that stays on forever!

I cannot post images yet but I can send u one, it says "Connecting to database.."

I get this pop up only when I have set the popup to appear through post_login_procedure ,
If i remove that then I can connect to interactive sql without any problem.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: why do you want to pop this up? i would rather save the login attempts into a table which you can query anytime you want.

Comment: I do save the login attempts in table, but I need to show the user a message on successful login that shows details about last login, failed login attempts etc.